# Rails sort collection by association count

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm working in Rails 4, and have two relevant models:

**Account Model**
`has_many :agent_recalls, primary_key: "id", :foreign_key => "pickup_agent_id", class_name: "Booking"`

Hence, queries like `Account.find(10).agent_recalls` would work.

What I want to do is sort the entire Account collection by this `agent_recalls` association.

Ideally it'd look something like (but obviously not):

`@agents = Account.where(agent: true).order(:agent_recalls)`

**Question:** What's the correct query to output an ordered list, by this `agent_recall` count?

Comment: do you mean something like `Account.where(agent: true).order("agent_recalls ASC")` or `Account.where(agent: true).order("agent_recalls DESC")`???

Comment: either one @DemiMagus. Both throw the error that the `agent_recalls` column does not exist

Comment: can you verify in the rails console the Account model? just writing the name of the class it should prompt the fields, is there the `agent_recalls` column? do you have some pending migrations?

Comment: `agent_recalls` isn't a column, it's an association as defined in the Account Model above.  What I want to do is order Account.all by this `agent_recalls` association count

Comment: @DemiMagus `2.1.4 :006 > Account
 => Account(id: integer, agent: boolean, dogfooder: boolean, email: string, first_name: string, last_name: string, phone: string, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, creation_time: integer, gender: string) `

Answer (score 1):

Well to accomplish what you are looking for you have 2 options:

first, only a query, but it will implied a join, so there will be lost the Accounts that doesn't have any agent_recalls, so i will discard this option

second, i think this one is more appropriate for what you are trying to do

```
Account.find(:all, :conditions => { :agent => true }, :include => :agent_recalls).sort_by {|a| a. agent_recalls.size}
```

As you can see is a mix between a query and ruby, hope it helps :)